# Shortest and Longest word in a sentence in Java

Tags: java, cpu-word

I am new in Java Programming! So tried to solve a problem to find the shortest and longest word in a sentence. My program is shown below . I hope you people can show me the right direction about my program -

```
public class StringProblems {
    void shortAndLongWord(String str) {
        String sw = "", lw = "";
        int s = str.length(), l = 0;
        String words[] = str.split(" ");

        for(String word:words) {
            if(word.length()<s)
                sw = word;
            else if(word.length()>l)
                lw = word;
        }

        System.out.println("LONGEST WORD : "+lw);
        System.out.println("SHORTEST WORD : "+sw);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);

        StringProblems obj = new StringProblems();
        System.out.printf("Enter a line to get shortest and longest word:");
        String str = scr.nextLine();
        str += " ";
        obj.shortAndLongWord(str);
    }
}
```

**Output of this program is :**
*Enter a line to get shortest and logest word:This is Sentence

LONGEST WORD : 
SHORTEST WORD : Sentence**

I dont know where my logic went wrong! Please help me to solve!

Comment: Once you have your current implementation technique working, try to solve this *without* creating a string array. Compare the difference in speed.

Comment: I will sure try that too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to keep updating the length of the current shortest and longest word:

```
public class StringProblems {
    void shortAndLongWord(String str)
    {
        if (str == null)
            return;
        String sw="",lw="";
        int s=str.length(),l=0;
        String words[]=str.split(" ");
        for(String word:words)
        {
                if(word.length()<s)
                {
                        sw=word;
                        s = word.length();
                }
                if(word.length()>l)
                {
                        lw=word;
                        l = word.length();
                }
        }
        System.out.println("LONGEST WORD : "+lw);
        System.out.println("SHORTEST WORD : "+sw);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scr=new Scanner(System.in);
        StringProblems obj=new StringProblems();
        System.out.printf("Enter a line to get shortest and longest word:");
        String str=scr.nextLine();
        str+=" ";
        obj.shortAndLongWord(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: nitpick, but it should be an if instead of an else if since the longest and shortest words could be the same.

Comment: Thanks @KevinDiTraglia after changing else if with if the programs runs fine.. ! Ans thanks for your input in the code jh314 !

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep updating `l` (length of the longest word) and `s` (length of the smallest word)

```
if(word.length()<s)
{
        sw=word;
        s = word.length();
}
if(word.length()>l)
{
        lw=word;
        l = word.length();
}
```

Also, there are boundary conditions that you need to take care of.
For example, what happens if the string is a single word. What happens when the input string is null etc.

Comment: Genuine question, would a null string return `word.Length() == 0`? Or would that cause a `Null Reference Exception`?

Comment: I did. Problem is half solved now coz after running I found -
Enter a line to get shortest and logest word:hkkh kk hm
LONGEST WORD : hm
SHORTEST WORD : kk
(sorry for random checking ! But higest word should be 'hkkh' right? )

Comment: @McAdam331 NullPointerException

Comment: Makes sense. I reread your comment and misunderstood. Is it even possible to have a `string.Length()` equal to 0? Perhaps for `String s = "";`?

Comment: That's correct. For an empty string, the length is 0.

Comment: I'm glad you brought that up. Too often it is my instinct to check for empty strings but not null input, and makes me wonder how many small bugs have gone unnoticed, or perhaps just verified elsewhere.

Comment: @Satyaki the second check should not be `else if` but just `if`. @McAdam331 I typically use apache-commons `StringUtils.isBlank()` [Typically apache-commons is included in all of my projects] just to avoid remembering to add 2 checks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating values of `l` and `s` during iteration. You should try something like this:

```
if (word.length() < s) {
    sw = word;
    s = word.length();
} else if (word.length() > l) {
    lw = word;
    l = word.length();
}
```

Comment: after changing else if with if the programs runs fine.. ! Thanks for your input ! I miss the word.length() part totally!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShortestAndLongestWordInALine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter any sentence : ");
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();
        int shortestWordLength = 0;
        int longestWordLength = 0;

        String shortestWord = "";
        String longestWord = "";

        int tempLength = 0;
        String[] eachWordArray = line.split(" ");
        boolean firstTime = false;
        for (String eachWord : eachWordArray) {
            tempLength = eachWord.length();
            if (firstTime == false) {
                firstTime = true;
                shortestWordLength = tempLength;
                shortestWord = eachWord;
                longestWordLength = tempLength;
                longestWord = eachWord;
            }

            if (tempLength > 0) {
                if (tempLength < shortestWordLength) {
                    shortestWordLength = tempLength;
                    shortestWord = eachWord;
                } else if (tempLength > longestWordLength) {
                    longestWordLength = tempLength;
                    longestWord = eachWord;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("shortestWordLength = " + shortestWordLength + " shortestWord = " + shortestWord);
        System.out.println("longestWordLength = " + longestWordLength + " longestWord = " + longestWord);

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;

class lw

{

  public static void main()

{

 Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

      String z=" ",lw="";
        int q=0,o=0;
        System.out.println("Enter string");
        String str=in.nextLine()+" ";
        int l=str.length();
        for(int i=1;i<l;i++)
        {
            char ch=str.charAt(i);
            if(ch!=' ')
                z=z+ch; 
            else
            {
                q=z.length();                
                if(q>o)
                lw=z;
                o=q;
                z="";
            }
        }
        System.out.println("lw= "+lw);
        System.out.println("length="+q);
    }
}
```